# Discord.py Attribute Error ('dict' object has no attribute 'id')

Tags: python, json, discord, bots, attributeerror

So I am following a tutorial on how to make an economy bot and now anytime I try to put in a command, it responds with this error!

```
File "main.py", line 164, in open_account
    if str(user.id) in users:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/EconomyCurrencyBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/EconomyCurrencyBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/EconomyCurrencyBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Here is the code in main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import keep_alive
import json
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
  await open_account(ctx.author)

  user = ctx.author
  users = await get_bank_data()

  wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
  bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
  
  em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color = discord.Color.red())
  em.add_field(name = "Wallet",value = wallet_amt)
  em.add_field(name = "Bank",value = bank_amt)
  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@bot.command()
async def beg(ctx):
  await open_account(ctx.author)

  user = ctx.author
  users = await get_bank_data()

  earnings = random.randrange(101)
  
  await ctx.send(f"Someone gave you {earnings} coins!")
  
  users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

  with open("MainBank.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)


@bot.command()
async def deposit(ctx,amount = None):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  if amount == None:
    await ctx.send('Please enter the amount you want to deposit')
    return 

  bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
  amount = int(amount)
  if amount>bal[0]:
    await ctx.send('You do not have enough money!')
    return
  if amount<bal[0]:
    await ctx.send('Number must be in the positives!')
    return

  await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount)
  await update_bank(ctx.author,amount,"bank")
  await ctx.send('Deposit Succesful!')

@bot.command()
async def send(ctx,member:discord.member, amount = None):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  await open_account(member)
  if amount == None:
    await ctx.send('Please enter the amount you want to send')
    return 

  bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
  if amount == "all":
    amount = bal[0]
  amount = int(amount)
  if amount>bal[1]:
    await ctx.send('You do not have enough money!')
    return
  if amount<bal[0]:
    await ctx.send('Number must be in the positives!')
    return

  await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount,"bank")
  await update_bank(member,amount,"bank")
  await ctx.send("Succesfully gave" + {amount} + "of coins!")

@bot.command()
async def rob(ctx,member:discord.member):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  await open_account(member)

  bal = await update_bank(member)
  if bal[0]<100:
    await ctx.send('He does not have enough money!')
    return

    earnings = random.randrange(100, bal[0])
  
  await update_bank(ctx.author,earnings)
  await update_bank(member,-1*earnings)
  await ctx.send('Rob went succesful!')

@bot.command()
async def slots(ctx,amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    if amount == None:
      await ctx.send('Please enter the amount you want to deposit')
    return 

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[0]:
      await ctx.send('You do not have enough money!')
      return
    if amount<bal[0]:
      await ctx.send('Number must be in the positives!')
      return
    final = []
    for i in range(3):
      a = random.choice(["X","W","O","I","E"])

      final.append(a)

    await ctx.send(str(final))
  
    if final[0] == final[1] or final[0] == final[2] or final[2] == final[1]:
      await update_bank(ctx.author,3*amount)
      await ctx.send("You Won!")
    else:
      await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount)
      await ctx.send("You lost!")

@bot.command()
async def withdraw(ctx,amount = None):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  if amount == None:
    await ctx.send('Please enter the amount you want to withdraw')
    return 

  bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
  amount = int(amount)
  if amount>bal[1]:
    await ctx.send('You do not have enough money!')
    return
  if amount<bal[0]:
    await ctx.send('Number must be in the positives!')
    return

  await update_bank(ctx.author,amount)
  await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount,"bank")
  await ctx.send('Withdraw Succesful!')

async def open_account(user):

  users = await get_bank_data()
  
  with open("MainBank.json","r") as f:
    user = json.load(f)

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

  with open("MainBank.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
  return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("MainBank.json","r") as f:
      users = json.load(f)

    return users

async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "wallet"):
  users = await get_bank_data()

  users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

  with open("MainBank.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)

  bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"],users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
  return bal

keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv('Token'))
```

and here is the code in my json file

```
{"903639795824214014": {"wallet":0, "bank":0}}
```

I am sure that this would be a very simple fix to this and I hope someone can help. The tutorial I watched has 3 parts but I only watched the first 2 since the 3rd part was just adding another command. Here are the 2 links to the 1st and 2nd part of the tutorial:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPaadO_sRD4
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ap_8jy_bLE

Comment: the numbers in my json file is my User ID on discord

Comment: There are two different arguments that you pass to `open_account()`, 1) `ctx.author` 2) `member`.
Have you verified that those variables both have the same structure? 
In all other locations where you reference `user.id`, you previously set `user = ctx.author`

I'm going to take a guess that discord.member is a dictionary and not an instance of a class, so you would have to access the user.id from it as `member["id"]` or find some way to normalize the two data structures.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I do not have a dictionary for discord.member and I am using replit to code this bot. I do not know how to normalize these 2 structures, if you know someone who can please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

[`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) returns a Python `dict`. So when loading the user, it will not return a `Discord.User` object, it will return a dictionary. Therefore, you must use `user['id']`.

EDIT: Instead of `user['id']` (My mistake, sorry) use

`user[str(whatever_your_users_id_is)]`

Your JSON keys are the user ids, so when you use json.load(), it returns a dictionary like the one in your json file.

I would recommend using Repl.it's built in database, it works exactly like a dictionary but it saves even on code rerun.

https://pypi.org/project/replit/

https://docs.replit.com/hosting/database-faq

https://replit.com/@util/Replit-Database-proxy (fork this)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now I get this error
`File "main.py", line 173, in open_account
    if str(user['id']) in users:
KeyError: 'id'`

Comment: How would I do it for if I enter someone elses ID, like what if someone elses uses it, then what should I do? It will just only return my Balance if I do the command

Comment: its still giving mr the error `File "main.py", line 173, in open_account
    if str(user[str(903639795824214017)]) in users:
KeyError: '903639795824214017'`